# Loading javascripts from src to inline problem

Tags: javascript, html, apache, google-chrome, debian

I generate from server html markup for small JS files like this:

```
<script defer src="external-script.js"></script>
```

But in Chrome I see:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" defer>
//<![CDATA[
.... content of my JS file
//]]>
</script>
```

Why? Who and how did it? It breaks my order loading scripts.
Problem is that defer working with src attribute only. When source code is inside , then defer is not accepted and I have some undefined functions called.

Comment: What exactly is broke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments I found that on hosting server is installed Pagespeed module which dooing this change.

I fixed put this into my htaccess:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeedDisableFilters inline_javascript
</IfModule>
```